# What is an 'cv2.reg_MapperGradEuclid' object? (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, types

I am trying to do some image registration with OpenCV 4 and Python 3.6. Two dicom files are loaded and the pixel data is handled as `numpy.ndarray`. When I try to pass these arrays to the `cv2.reg_MapperGradEuclid.calculate()` function, the following error is raised:

> descriptor 'calculate' requires a `cv2.reg_MapperGradEuclid` object
>   but received a 'numpy.ndarray'

I looked up the documentation and several threads, all I found was that there should be two `InputArray` ´s that should be of the BGR type(?) and that technically `np.ndarray` should work.

```
    import numpy as np    
    import pydicom    
    import cv2    

    file1="one.DCM"    
    file2="two.DCM"    
    data1 = pydicom.read_file(file1)    
    data2 = pydicom.read_file(file2)    

    PixelArrayBelow = data1.pixel_array         #type np.ndarray
    PixelArrayAbove = data2.pixel_array    

    PixelArrayBelow=PixelArrayBelow.astype(np.float32)    
    PixelArrayAbove=PixelArrayAbove.astype(np.float32)    

    BelowNew=cv2.cvtColor(PixelArrayBelow,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)    
    AboveNew=cv2.cvtColor(PixelArrayAbove,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)    

    b = cv2.reg_MapperGradEuclid.calculate(BelowNew,AboveNew)    
    print(b)
```

I expected it to print some combination of translation and rotation vector/matrix, but the above mentioned error occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `reg_MapperGradEuclid()` object first and then pass the images into the object it seems to work. You are not calling the object properly.

```
import cv2

im1 = <some numpy array>
im2 = <some numpy array>

mge_obj = cv2.reg_MapperGradEuclid()
retval = mge_obj.calculate(im1, im2)
```

So to make it work with your code change:

`b = cv2.reg_MapperGradEuclid.calculate(BelowNew,AboveNew)`

to:

`b = cv2.reg_MapperGradEuclid().calculate(BelowNew,AboveNew)`

The class documentation is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d51/classcv_1_1reg_1_1MapperGradEuclid.html) but it's quite basic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Either the documentation lacks some very important things or I just cant find them, because the resulting registration Map, again, cannot be handled easily. Instead of a 'cv2.reg_MapAffine' I get a 'cv2.reg_Map'. Its not possible to read shift and linear transformation from the latter one.

Comment: does `b = cv2.reg_MapperGradAffine().calculate(BelowNew,AboveNew)` give you the right result?

Comment: It didn´t, but `reg.MapTypeCaster_toAffine()` , which was again hidden somewhere in the Documentation did. Thanks anyways!