# How to access angle and shift information in cv2-reg (OpenCV)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-registration, opencv-stitching

I have trouble with accessing angle and shift information from the cv2.reg objects [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d61/group__reg.html). They cannot be called directly as already discussed in [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022282/what-is-an-cv2-reg-mappergradeuclid-object-opencv).

Based on the discussion in the link above and on the very spartan documentation, this is my code, which does not lead to any errors, but leads to inaccessible objects:

```
a = cv2.reg_MapperGradAffine()
b = cv2.reg.MapperPyramid(a)
retval = b.calculate(im1, im2)
c = cv2.reg.MapTypeCaster_toAffine(retval)
```

It is also not clear to me what is meant by "sourceMap" in the "MapTypeCaster Class" [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d1b/classcv_1_1reg_1_1MapTypeCaster.html)?

Many thanks in advance!

If further information is needed, please tell me!

@D.Griffiths or @Mettphysik, maybe do you remember how to solve this? You both already worked on this problem.